# sending mail using smtp.gmail.com in azure App Service asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-appservice

I try to send email in asp.net core (MVC) using smtp.gmail.com when I use this code

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
                        message.To.Add(user.Email);
                        message.Subject = " Confirmation mail";
                        message.Body = "Welcome to our site \n  Please Confirm you Email by click the link below  " + $"<a href=\"{Clink}\">Verfiy Email</a>";
                        message.From = new MailAddress("mail@gmail.com");
                        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
                        System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
                        smtp.Port = 587; // 465or433
                        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; 
                        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("mail@gmail.com", "pass");
                        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                        smtp.Send(message);
```

when I try it before uploading the web to azure app service  it's work but after I upload not work and don't show me the error
I try to use these ports (587, 465, 433) but not work too

Comment: when using port 587 can you try setting EnableSsl=false..Also in .Net core SmtpClient is not recommended as per official documentation, if possible try using MailKit as per the official Microsoft guidelines https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: oky i will try it

Comment: i try it and it's not work